# Submit button disable on click not calling correct method - calls execute() only

Tags: jquery, struts2, submit, double-submit-problem

I've searched and found answers how to disable all submit buttons when clicked to prevent double form submission.

```
$('#annCreateEdit').click(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Unfortunately, the effect it has means the correct struts 2 method is no longer being called, it is defaulting to calling the execute() method.

My JavaScript skills are very poor and by extension so too are my jQuery skills.

Assistance with disabling the (or all) submit buttons while still calling the correct method would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/token-interceptor.html.

Comment: for double submission you can take look at the link for `token-interceptor` as mentioned by `Aleksandr`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#annCreateEdit').click(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    return false;
 });
```

If you are using `Jquery 1.6` or above then you can use also as below:

```
 $('#annCreateEdit').click(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    return false;
 });
```

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7.1 so I tried both. The buttons are disabled but the form does not get submitted at all :-/

Comment: What you want on disable?

Comment: I want to disable the button when it's submitted but for the first submit to call the correct method in the action class.  E.g. here's one of the buttons:       <s:submit id="wizPrevious" key="button.wizard.prev" method="wizPreviousWiz" cssClass="btn btn-info toptip btnImgL wizPrev span2" title="%{getText('tt.wizPrevious')}" />